# Null pointer exception for async task

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

I am dealing with my web services and I got a strange problem and I couldn't able to solve this as I am new to android development. I am getting null pointer exception while I am showing the toast in `onPostExecute()` method of async task. some one please help me to fix this

```
if (result.booleanValue()) // here at this line I am getting the error in logcat//
```

Thanks in advance....!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ///////////male female buttons code/////////////
    Button regmalebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regmalebtn); 
    regmalebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gender="M";
            System.out.println("gender value after  male button click ="+gender);
            Log.v(TAG,"gender value on  male button click ="+gender );
        }
    });
    Button regfemalebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regfemalebtn);
    regfemalebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gender ="F";
            // System.out.println("gender value on  female button click ="+gender);
            Log.v(TAG,"gender value on  female button click ="+gender );
        }
    });

    ////////////male female button code will ends here/////////////

    Button signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regsubmitbtn);
    signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new RegisterTask().execute();
        };
    });
}


private class RegisterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Registering...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }


    //  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final Void unused) {
        return this.register(); //don't interact with the ui!
    }

    private Boolean register() {
        ************some code for webservices************
    }

    return null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
    if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
    }
    if (result.booleanValue()) {
        // show register success dialog
        // I m getting the error at above line

        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return register();
}


}   
}
```

These r the logcat errors

```
06-28 16:55:56.685: WARN/dalvikvm(708): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at com.soap.Register$RegisterTask.onPostExecute(Register.java:193)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at com.soap.Register$RegisterTask.onPostExecute(Register.java:1)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 16:55:56.695: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(708):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
```

Comment: http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-async-task.html

Comment: how to make a null check before calling result.booleanValue()?

Comment: I tried with the below suggestions but its only showing progress dialog as output, nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are obviously returning null from register method. Either return something that isn't null or make a null check before calling `result.booleanValue()`.

You could do that like this:

```
if (result == null) {

}
else if (result.booleanValue()) {

}
else {

}
```

By the way, why do you need to return a Boolean and not boolean (primitive type, which can't be null).

Comment: Thanks for ur response, but could you help with code snippet, I m confused a bit

Comment: how to make a null check before calling result.booleanValue()?

Comment: Thanks once again, I want to check the result of logcat if its 1 then I should show a toast or alert like "REGISTERD" Ootherwise "TRYAGAIN"

Comment: I tried but only progress dialog is showing and nothing, after few minutes force closing

Answer (score 0):

Try using as argument of the Toast the name of your activity.class. I think in your case is Register.class instead of Register.this

Comment: If I use register.class  I m getting error like    The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Register>, String, int)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context, java.lang.CharSequence, int)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the context into variable. Or try `Register.this.getApplicationContext()` or `BaseContext`. Check if the dialog is null, make the pass the values and create new dialog in the `postExecute()` if that does not overlap from your requirements :)

Comment: Thanks, but how to check the null value in order to not return null,bit confused

Comment: @Raj Check like this if(dialog != null) { do the rest of operation }; so if the dialog is null, then nothing will happen. If the dialog is not null then operations proceed regularly.

Comment: Thanks , I got the prblm with my toast according to logcat response.In every case I m getting "Try again" if (resultsRequestSOAP == null) {
        Toast.makeText(Register.this.getApplicationContext(), "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       else if (resultsRequestSOAP.booleanValue()) {
       //also show register success dialog
        Toast.makeText(Register.this.getApplicationContext(), "Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       }
       else{
        Toast.makeText(Register.this.getBaseContext(), "Field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

Answer (score 0):

i've written this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

            Toast.makeText(
                    myclassname.this,
                    "Downloading of " + FILENAME
                            + " complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            refreshList();


        }
```

and this is workning for me..

[see this link for more detail](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-download-files-with-progress-dialog/)
 http://hi.baidu.com/hi_android/blog/item/fea149f90da7fdedfd037f56.html
 http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746

Comment: @Pragana, Thanks , I got the prblm with my toast according to logcat response.In every case I m getting "Try again" if (resultsRequestSOAP == null) {
        Toast.makeText(Register.this.getApplicationContext(), "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       else if (resultsRequestSOAP.booleanValue()) {
       //also show register success dialog
        Toast.makeText(Register.this.getApplicationContext(), "Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


       }
       else{
        Toast.makeText(Register.this.getBaseContext(), "Field is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the same Toast/Async/Nullpointe problem by launching Toasts like this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```